# Unable to connect to SQL Failover Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

I have a a SQL Server 2005 Failover Cluster with two nodes.  Node A & Node B.  SQL is running on Node B.  About 2 weeks ago, we failed over to Node A.  Then after the problem was corrected, we failed back to Node B.  Everything seems good, and I see no errors in the system or Application Event Logs on the boxes.  They are both running Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and SQL 2005 Enterprise.

I have two web servers, both running Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.  Both boxes are on the same subnet.  Since failover that occurred 2 weeks ago, Server 1 works normally, but server 2 is unable to connect to sql on the cluster.  Nothing has changed on either web server.  Server 2 cannot ping the cluster name or IP address; however, it does resolve the name to the correct IP Address.  Server 2 can ping both nodes individually (on the same subnet as the cluster IP).  I'm completely at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any thoughts / suggestions would be wildly helpful.

Comment: Firstly - Can you load Failover Cluster Manager and re-validate the cluster? What warnings do you get? Two separate things at play here: Are the webservers clones of each other? Are they in an NLB? What type of NLB? They may be configured differently. If you fail the cluster back over can both webservers ping the Cluster name or VIP? Was the Cluster Name failed over successfully? Since you can ping by individual server name, I imagine the cluster name will be our troubleshooting point tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In failover cluster manager on the cluster network resource that should be responsive to client connections (LAN), verify that "allow cluster network communication on this network" and "allow clients to connect through this network: are both selected.  I don't know that this is your problem, but it's the first thing I would check.

[image]